# Matlab: how to pass a vector to be the initial condition in pdetool

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I'm using `pdetool box` to solve a 2D diffusion problem. My initial condition is the solutions  of another 2D problem (solved using the `pdenonlin function`). How to pass the solutions of the `pdenonlin function` to be the initial condition in `pdetool box` ? Any help is appreciated